# Javascript array from JSON not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I quite don't understand what's going on here, probably due to my lack of knowledge in JSON.

I have a php script returning a JSON into an ajax query (with `dataType:'json'`). Here is what I end up with in the javascript :

```
 alert(JSON.stringify(data.polylines[i]));
```

I guess `data.polylines[i]` is already an object as I need `JSON.stringify()` function to show it properly. This alert shows :

```
 [["40.632099151611","8.2907695770263"],["57.774700164794","11.870400428772"]]
```

which is exactly the array I need for the variable `path` in the following script (drawing a line in Google Maps Api):

```
map.drawPolyline({
     path: path,
     strokeColor: '#131540',
     strokeOpacity: 0.6,
     strokeWeight: 6
});
```

when I do :

```
 var path = data.polylines[i];
 map.drawPolyline({
     path: path,
     strokeColor: '#131540',
     strokeOpacity: 0.6,
     strokeWeight: 6
});
```

... it's not working, but when I do :

```
var path = [["40.632099151611","8.2907695770263"],["57.774700164794","11.870400428772"]];
 map.drawPolyline({
     path: path,
     strokeColor: '#131540',
     strokeOpacity: 0.6,
     strokeWeight: 6
});
```

it works. I can't figure out why one works and not the other one, as the 'alert' test shows exactly the same value...

Comment: What is `path` when you set it to `data.polylines[i]`?

Comment: What is `i`? Is this in a loop?

Comment: Could data.polylines[i] be giving you a string instead of an array?  For example: '[["40.632099151611","8.2907695770263"],["57.774700164794","11.870400428772"]]'.  Try using console.log instead of alert to see if thats the case.

Comment: Yes, the whole thing is in a loop as I'm drawing several distinct lines. For clarification, here is the json output : `{"polylines":[[["40.632099151611","8.2907695770263"],["57.774700164794","11.870400428772"]],[["40.632099151611","8.2907695770263"],["41.901000976562","2.7605500221252"]]]}`.

Comment: @Fredovsky - you should post the whole loop, as I'm about 95% certain that that is where the real problem is.

Comment: Have you tried doing `var path = JSON.parse(data.polylines[i]);` or even `var path = JSON.stringify(data.polylines[i]);`

Comment: @Pointy You were right, my loop condition was wrong. Bloody copy/paste. Thanks. Not sure how to close the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my mistake was in the loop condition as pointed out by @Pointy. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Path is a Collection of two or more points and each Point is an array of two coords. When you use polylines[i] you Are trying to Draw a path with one point, which Will fail